# System Health OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio

What the difference betwen Open JDK and Oracle JDK?

As far as i understand they work the same. I worked with OpenCV and maybe while i was trying download OpenCV library i downloaded also OpenJDK. And now i all the time get such message:

```
"System Health
OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK."
```

I try looking for info about it but don't understand exextly...

And now i should redownload it or i can work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I Google for the phrase "System Health OpenJDK" I see a few hits in blogs and the like:

- The message appears for be coming from Android Studio, not OpenCV
- The consensus seems to be that you can ignore it.

---

Separately to that, [these](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) OpenCV for Java build instructions say:

> ... In order to build OpenCV with Java bindings you need JDK (**we recommend Oracle/Sun JDK 6 or 7**), Apache Ant and Python v2.6 or higher to be installed.

The "we recommend" could simply be because that the OpenCV team build and test using Oracle JDKs and not OpenJDK.  And clearly, those instructions have not been updated in some time, so it is hard to know if any (hypothetical) issues with OpenJDK are still current, or how they relate to *running* OpenCV.

So which is *actually* more stable?  I don't know, and I can't think of a scientific way to find out.

Personally ... I'd stick with what I had downloaded for now.   If I ran into problems that I thought might be the JRE's fault, I would try out the alternative to see if it made a difference.

Comment: sorry for my englisg, but if i want work with OpenCV it will be better if i use OracleJDK?

Comment: I think I answered that in my last sentence.  There is no scientific way to answer that question.

Comment: @StephenC you mention "the consensus". Thanks, I'll ignore the warning for now. Any source for "the consensus"?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko to put it short: if you already have OpenJDK installed, continue with it. Only if you experience a problem consider using OracleJDK. Also, consider having both JDK available so that when a problem happens you can test with the other to see if it cures the problem.

Comment: *"Any source for "the consensus"?"* - I said the consensus **seems to be** ...  That is shorthand for me saying that I Googled, I read some search results, and I couldn't find anyone who said this was an actual problem.  If you come across someone who presents evidence or a credible argument that there >>is<< a problem ... I would change my "there seems to be" statement.